# Error only on Deploy, after migrating from Angular 4 to Angular 6

Tags: angular, azure, deployment

I just migrated my Angular 4 application to Angular 6. Everything is working fine when I serve the application. I can build the application for production using the command *ng build --configuration=production --aot* with no errors. But after I deploy the application to Azure I receive the following error in the browser: [SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMt20.png)

Comment: You don't *build* your application with `ng serve`. Consider actually **building** your application with `ng build`. And please, provide your error as text. It's initially text, I don't see the point of converting it to an image.

Comment: Sorry @trichetriche . My mistake. The command I am using for build is `ng build --configuration=production --aot`. And the error that I have is *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'*

Comment: Again, please post your error as code. Knowing only what type of error it is won't help much, we need to know where it comes from. And by the way, you can shorten your command to `ng build --prod`, this does the same thing plus some other cool stuff, such as for instance, cache busting

Comment: This error is not in my terminal, is in my browser console. Serve and build are completed with no error in the terminal. This is my application: [link](https://testgsforms.azurewebsites.net/). You will see the errors in the browser console.

Comment: I know it's in your application, that doesn't mean you can't copy paste it. And I'm on phone, I don't have access to dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error four times: *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'*. In *runtime, polyfils, scripts and main*. If I click on either one of them  I get the same thing - my *index.html* which looks fine in my opinion:`

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <title>GSForms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.857e9318f3b585c2337e.css"></head>
    <body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
        <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.11fb201fd2c05ba12fc0.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.20018d896dce3cebbe96.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.1e4e4f091818d4dc5906.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.259052feb397b3d6fc3b.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`